# How is the adjective תַּחְתִּיִּ֛ם functioning independently in Genesis 6:16

Tags: genesis, hebrew-bible

In Genesis 6:16 we read,"...side thereof; with lower, second, and third stories..." (KJV)

The word, *second, third* are both ordinal numbers but the word *lower* is an adjective which is not qualifying any noun. How do we understand the function of this adjective?

Comment: The text actually reads: " ... with lower, second and third you shall make it."  That is, the noun for "decks" or "stories" does not exist in the verse.

Comment: It may imply that the human living quarters were on the 'second'. Thus, from a human inhabitant viewpoint, the 'first' would be below.

Answer (score 2):

I got it, it is because it is a substantive adjective.